# Identify directory other than some selected directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I'm working on a shell script and having one issue.
If I have a file with list of directory and files info like:

```
home/svdev/src/lib
home/dev/project/doc
home/server/etc
dev.dump/trunk/src
dev.dump/src/etc
etc/hosts
template.txt
admin/releases/tables
```

I want to identify if any directory or file is there which isn't starting with **home** and **dev.dump**. So for the given data as the last three entries are matching directory condition, so I should get *False* as my output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `grep(1)` and an `if-statement`

```
if grep -Evq '^(home|dev\.dump).*' file.txt ; then echo false; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` for this:

```
$ cat good
home/svdev/src/lib
home/dev/project/doc
home/server/etc

dev.dump/trunk/src
dev.dump/src/etc
$

$ cat bad
home/svdev/src/lib
home/dev/project/doc
home/server/etc

dev.dump/trunk/src
dev.dump/src/etc

etc/hosts
template.txt
admin/releases/tables
$

$ if grep -q -v -E '^home/|^dev\.dump/|^[[:space:]]*$' good; then echo false; else echo true; fi
true

$ if grep -q -v -E '^home/|^dev\.dump/|^[[:space:]]*$' bad; then echo false; else echo true; fi
false
```

For the `grep` I used `^home/|^dev\.dump/|^[[:space:]]*$`, that means "search for lines that start (`^`) with home/ or (`|`) start (`^`) with dev.dump/" or (`|`) blank line that can optionally contain whitespace characters(`^[[:space:]]*$`).  The `-E` option causes `grep` to apply the pattern as an extended regular expression.  The `-v` option inverts the match, so it matches lines that do not match the pattern.  "Good" files will have no lines that match the inverted pattern, "bad" files will have lines.  The `-q` option causes `grep` to suppress output.

If `grep` finds a match, it will exit with 0; if there is no match, it will exit with a non-zero value.  I use the shell's `if` to check `grep`'s exit value, and to print the corresponding `true`/`false` strings accordingly.

Comment: Note an empty line in the file will trigger `false`. Formally an empty line cannot identify a "directory or file", so the condition "any directory or file is there which isn't starting with `home` and `dev.dump`" is not fulfilled solely by it. Any non-empty line can identify a file (unless it contains NULL), so the empty line seems the only edge case. I'm pointing this out because your answer looks like there was an empty line at the end of each file; until one realizes the newlines are like *in the prompt*. I'm aware you probably inserted these newlines to make the answer more readable.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Good point, thank you -- I didn't consider the use case where the file contained blank lines.  I've edited my solution to handle that case, and updated the sample content of the two files to emphasize that it does contain blank lines.